# One-click OpenAPI/Swagger build architecture for backend server code

Tags: spring, flask, swagger, openapi

I use swagger to generate both client/server api code. On my frontend (react/ts/axios), integrating the generated code is very easy: I make a change to my spec, consume the new version through NPM, and immediately the new API methods are available

On the server side, however, the process is a lot more janky. I am using java, and I have to copy and paste specific directories over (such as the routes, data types etc) and a lot of the generated code doesn't play nice with my existing application (in terms of imports etc). I am having the same experience with a flask instance that I have.

I know that comparing client to server is apple to oranges, but is there a better way to construct a build architecture so that I don't have to go through this error prone/tedious process every time? Any pointers here?